# How do I add/remove from an array with the reducer within React Context?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-context, use-context, use-reducer

```js
import React from 'react';
import {useReducer, createContext } from 'react';

let initialState = {
  associatedOrgs:[],
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "logout":
      return initialState;
    
    case "set-associated-org":
      return {...state, associatedOrgs: action.payload };
    
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const UserContext = createContext(initialState);

const UserContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const logout = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: "logout",
    });
  };

  const setAssociatedOrg = (org) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "set-associated-org",
      payload: org,
    });
  };
  
  return(
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        associatedOrgs: state.associatedOrgs,
        logout,
        setAssociatedOrg
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
};

export default UserContextProvider;
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I fixed the formatting of your post, and while doing so I noticed you've got some nesting errors in the render section, within the props passed to the context provider. You don't actually state what problem you're having, so I could be off-base, but it's possible that was part of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

```js
case "add-associated-org":
  return {
    ...state,
    associatedOrgs: state.associatedOrgs.concat(action.orgToAdd)
  }

case "remove-associated-org":
  return {
    ...state,
    associatedOrgs: state.associatedOrgs.filter(org => org !== action.orgToRemove)
  }
```

Then you just need to define a couple action-creators that dispatch those events to your reducer; the pattern you have for `set-associated-orgs` should work (although it would be better to define them outside your component since they can be pure functions and there's no need to make the engine re-construct them on every render).

---

EDIT

**Q:** How would you pass the dispatch to the action creator if created outside?

**A:** (Excellent question.) I'd make each action-creator a pure function, and then wrap them all up in a function that binds them to a particular `dispatch`. Unfortunately, this results in reversing the performance gains. More on that in a bit.

Here's a quick-and-dirty first draft:

```js
function getActions( dispatch ) {
  const logout = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: "logout",
    });
  };
  
  const setAssociatedOrg = (org) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "set-associated-org",
      payload: org,
    });
  };
  
  return {
    logout,
    setAssociatedOrg
  }
}
```

And then inside the component I'd have:

```js
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
const actions = getActions(dispatch)
```

That won't scale very well, and for testing purposes each action-creator should be exported, so a better pattern would look like this:

```
// src/actions/index.js
export function logout( dispatch ) { /* impl */ }
export function setAssociatedOrgs( dispatch, orgs ) { /* impl */ }

// create a collection of all action creators so we can process them all
const ACTIONS = { logout, setAssociatedOrgs }

// app code should only ever import this function
// the other functions would be private if not for unit-testing
export default function bindActionsToDispatch( dispatch ) {
  return Object.keys(ACTIONS).reduce(( hash, actionCreatorName ) => ({
    ...hash,
    [actionCreatorName]: ACTIONS[actionCreatorName].bind(undefined, dispatch)
  }), {})
}
```

This has benefits and drawbacks.

One quirk of this approach is that each action creator is defined with an extra `dispatch` arg. The aggregator function makes that invisible to calling code (so, you'd still do `actions.setAssociatedOrgs(orgs)`), but I don't know what it'll look like to your IDE's syntax suggestions.

Like I said, I'm assuming this will re-introduce the performance penalty of re-defining all the action-creators on every component render, which is bad. And now I'm doing it with a bunch of extra code, which is worse.

So, if I were doing this, I would create a custom React hook built on top of `useReducer`; it would create the state container, define the root reducer, *and* bind all the action creators. (It makes sense to bind the actions creators at that point, because the set of actions that a store supports is determined by what reducer(s) it houses, and that is set when you provide the root reducer to `useReducer`. ) I'm pretty sure you can set all of that up in a way that will only execute once, with subsequent renders returning identical store & store-bound action-creators.

Using the new hook might look like this:

```js
let [ orgState, orgActions ] = useDucksStore(initialOrgState, orgReducers, orgActionCreators)

// and then:
orgActions.setAssociatedOrgs(newOrgs)
```

Stepping back, I think the "action creator" pattern is not a good fit for the bare `useReducer` hook. `useReducer` is nice because it's lightweight, and you're giving that up if you decide that every `dispatch` call has to be wrapped in a "Ducks"-style action creator. If Ducks is your thing, you really should build a custom hook to facilitate *and enforce* those access patterns. Otherwise you'll have to do all this work inside each component that wants to manage state similarly, not to mention whatever is the performance cost of reconstructing a miniature Ducks ecosystem on every blit.

Comment: How would you pass the dispatch to the action creator if created outsite?